# Denosing of extremely condensed signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, interpolation, smoothing

I am attempting to denoise a high-sampeled spectrum by removing all the sharp peaks and then performing a shape-preserving piecewise cubic spline interpolation to retain as much spectrum information as I can. However, I am not able to clear out all the peaks, including the one peak in the beginning. What am I missing - am I approaching this wisely? Btw., I have several of these spectra that I need to process. Many thanks for any input in advance!!

Signal data used are found [here](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/434484-denosing-of-extremely-condensed-signal).

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Attempt**

```
minval = 0;
maxval = 950;

figure();
plot(lambda, SI, '-')
xlabel('Wavelength')
ylabel('Signal Intensity')
ylim([minval maxval])
title('Original signal')

ind_min = find(SI <= minval);
ind_max = find(SI >= maxval);
lambda([ind_min.', ind_max.']) = [];
SI([ind_min.', ind_max.']) = [];

figure();
plot(lambda, SI, '-')
xlabel('Wavelength')
ylabel('Signal Intensity')
ylim([minval maxval])
title('Signal after removing all values above 950')

% Define threshold representing 25th percentile difference between signal values
diffSI = abs(diff(SI));
thres = quantile(diffSI, 0.25);

%% Remove all sharp peaks
% Remove all signal values differing from neighbouring values above 
% computed threshold and replace their values estimated by 
% shape-preserving piecewise cubic spline interpolation 
for i = 2:(length(SI) - 1)
    if abs(SI(i) - SI(i+1)) > thres
        SI(i) = NaN;
        SI(i+1) = NaN;
    elseif abs(SI(i) - SI(i-1)) > thres
        SI(i) = NaN;
        SI(i-1) = NaN;
    end
end
SI = fillmissing(SI, 'pchip');

figure()
plot(lambda, SI, '-')
xlabel('Wavelength')
ylabel('Signal Intensity')
ylim([minval maxval])
title('Signal after interpolation')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Image Processing toolbox, the [`imopen`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imopen.html) function is the filter for you. It applies a morphological opening to the data, which is a non-linear smoothing function that is biased to the low values (the closing is the reverse operation, biased towards the high values).

```
load ~/tmp/SI_and_lambda.mat
SI2=imopen(SI,ones(25,1));
plot(lambda,SI)
hold on
plot(lambda,SI2,'r')
```

[image: plot of data before and after filtering]

Note that [the `movmin` solution you got on your question on MATLAB Answers](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/434484-denosing-of-extremely-condensed-signal#answer_351106) will not track the lower envelope as closely as the `imopen` filter. You can plot these results on top of each other to see the difference.